# Sql query for AND on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table (tblABC) which looks like

```
-----------------------------
BasicID   | Filter 1| Filter2 |
------------------------------
 100          1         2
 100          3         4
 101          8         9
```

I want to select the BasicID which has Filter1=1 and Filter2=4. ie I want to get the output as
100

I can't be using AND here as as it searches within the same row only. ie 
`select * from tblABC where Filter1=1 and Filter2=4` , yields no result.

As of now the query that I use is

```
select * from tblABC  
where 
and BasicID in 
(
select BasicID from tblABC  
where Filter1 IN (1) 
)
and BasicID  in 
(
select BasicID from tblABC  
where Filter2 IN (4) 
)
```

This one works for me. But there are like 12 Filter columns and when such a string search is run in large volumes, wouldn't it make the query slow. What would be a more efficient way of doing this?

I am using Microsoft SQL 2014

Comment: Can Filter1 or Filter2 repeat a value for a particular BasicID?. This means: it is possible to have (100, 1, 2) (100, 1, 3) and (100, 5, 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
select basicid from tblABC where filter1 = 1 intersect 
select basicid from tblABC where filter1 = 4
```

Comment: Thanks Azar. Its working for me. But just wanted to know how efficient it would be to write 12 select queries and intersect them.

Answer (score 2):

If the two filter values can be either in different rows or the same row, the `GROUP BY / HAVING` method will fail (in the same row case). This method will work in all cases (the `intersect` query by @Azar will work, too):

```
select distinct a.BasicID 
from tblABC as a
  join tblABC as b
    on a.BasicID = b.BasicID
where a.Filter1 = 1 
  and b.Filter2 = 4 ;
```

---

If you want the `GROUP BY / HAVING COUNT` method, this modification will work in all cases, too:

```
select basicid
from   tblABC
where  filter1 = 1
   or  filter2 = 4
group by
       basicid
having count(case when filter1 = 1 then 1 end) >= 1
   and count(case when filter2 = 4 then 1 end) >= 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT BasicID
  FROM tblABC
  WHERE Filter1=1 OR Filter2=4
    GROUP BY BasicID
    HAVING COUNT(BasicID)=2
```

In case of 12 filters, change COUNT to be 12.

Comment: Thanks. But I cant be using this as both the Filters I required can also come in the same row. ie the first row of the table mentioned in the question could also be 
| 100 | 1 | 4 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and a `count` if you are sure one line doesn't match multiple rules (then the count might be off and the query breaks).

```
select basicid
from   tblABC
where  filter1 = 1
or     filter2 = 4
group
by     basicid
having count(*) = 2 /*number of filters*/
```

Comment: Thanks. But I cant be using this as both the Filters I required can also come in the same row. ie the first row of the table mentioned in the question could also be 
| 100 | 1 | 4 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT BasicId 
FROM  tblABC  main
WHERE Filter1 = 1
    AND  EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 Filter2
                 FROM tblABC
                 WHERE tblABC.BasicId =  main.BasicId
                   AND Filter2 = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the IN clause. You can easily create three additional variants: using exists instead of in, using intersection, and using a selfjoin of tblABC.

But as far as I know, query optimizers can translate automatically your query into these three variants and even it could get more non-trivial rewritings.

I suggest you:

- First, let the optimizer work.
- Second, if your query is finally slow then create (if not exists) a index over BasicID.
- Third, if the query is still slow then use two bitmap indexes, over filter1 and over filter2.
- And fourth if it is still slow use and indexed view.

Comment: How efficient would be using 12 select queries and using INTERSECT as suggested by @Azar here...?

Comment: There are too many unknown variables in your query to determine how efficient the query will be. If your problem is 12 sub-queries in one query… don't worry about it. Great RDBMS (SQL Server, Oracle, DB2…) many times decompose automatically a single query into into multiple sub-queries and merge their results. They can manage queries with much more than 12 sub-queries.