# Difficult SQL Request?

Tags: sql, select

I have this table `tagMusic`

```
id   tagid   musicid
---------------------
1     1       141
2     4       141
3     3       102
```

So I need to say:
take me all the music ID who have tag Id 1 AND 4 (for example ).

Comment: Because I've another column named "number", and I need to know how many tagId they are for avec music

Comment: No .. 'difficult' is is not. A vague title .. it is.

Comment: So, what is your solution ?

Comment: I recommend updating the title.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31289707/mysql-filter-and-query-on-multiple-fields-in-multiple-joined-rows , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887434/sql-query-for-and-on-multiple-rows

Comment: Please clarify the question with the details from your previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

One way about it is to select only those tags and count how many unique results you got per tag:

```
SELECT   musicid
FROM     tagmusic
WHERE    tagid IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY musicid
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: OMG It was so simple, I've a last question, Has what serves HAVING COUNT ?

Comment: `having` is a conditional clause that applies **after** the `group by`, so you can use it to filter aggregate expressions. Here, I use it to filer `musicid`s that have **both** tags (a count of 2), in order to remove `musicid`s that have just `tagid` of 1 or of 4.

Comment: I'm trying but this in a good solution in that case, but my table is extensible, and I'll have more than 2 tag for 1 music...

Comment: Just change the conditions in the `where` and `having` clauses accordingly.